# How do I ignore all data from an InputStream without tripping up static-analysis tools?

Tags: java, inputstream, findbugs

I have an `InputStream` that's attached to stdout of another process. I sometimes need to log data from the stream, and sometimes don't. Even when I don't care about the output, I still need to read it so that the other process doesn't block due to a full output buffer. I use the following code to selectively log the output:

```
InputStream is = ...;
boolean report = ...;
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
if (report) {
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Debug.println(line);
    }
} else {
    while (br.readLine() != null) {
    }
}
```

However, in the second `while` loop, FindBugs alerts (RV_DONT_JUST_NULL_CHECK_READLINE) that I'm calling `readLine` and *only* checking whether it's null, not doing anything with the result. Its analysis is correct, but I don't *want* to do anything with the result in that case. Is there some idiomatic way of consuming and ignoring all data from a stream such that it might not look like a mistake to FindBugs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid having to construct `String` objects that just get thrown away by using `skip` on the `InputStream`. (`InputStreamReader` and `BufferedReader` also have `skip` methods, but if you're looking to skip the *entire* stream, you don't really need the character-decoding features of `InputStreamReader` or the line-detection and buffer-management features of `BufferedReader`.)

```
while (is.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE) == Long.MAX_VALUE) {
}
```

It's unlikely the loop will ever run more than once — you'd need to read 8 exabytes off the stream first — but the loop is there to quell another FindBugs warning (SR_NO_CHECKED) that happens if you call `skip` without inspecting the return value.

---

Using the `SuppressWarnings` annotation to silence the compiler is ineffective because it's not the *compiler* that's worried about the unused return value. The annotation isn't stored in the compiled code, so byte-code analyzers like FindBugs can't see it anyway. Furthermore, none of the warnings that `SuppressWarnings` suppresses applies in this situation; in particular, `unused` doesn't apply because *return values* aren't among the things the compiler checks.

Instead of the Java built-in `SuppressWarnings`, though, you can try using some other suppression mechanism provided by the static-analysis tool that's generating the warning. In the case of FindBugs, that's the `SuppressFBWarnings` annotation.

```
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings;
```

To minimize the scope of the warning suppression, you can isolate the warning-generating code in its own method. For example:

```
@SuppressFBWarnings("RV_DONT_JUST_NULL_CHECK_READLINE")
private void consumeWholeStream(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    while (br.readLine() != null) {
    }
}
```

Then you can use that method in the given context:

```
if (report) {
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Debug.println(line);
    }
} else {
    consumeWholeStream(br);
}
```

The caveat is that this adds the FindBugs annotation jar to your build dependencies. It's not added to the program's *run-time* dependencies, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try using @SuppressWarnings notation.

Check this link [Excluding warnings using @SuppressWarnings](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-suppress_warnings.htm)

Some notes about it:

*"Without the annotation, the compiler would complain that the local variable s is never used. With the annotation, the compiler silently ignores this warning locally to the foo method. This enables to keep the warnings in other locations of the same compilation unit or the same project."*

Comment: @SuppressWarnings is superior to other solutions involving syntax tricks to shut the warning up because it is self-documenting:  you tell future readers of your code (possibly yourself) you meant to do that.

Comment: But @BadZen, doesn't it also tell readers that I meant to do all the other potential mistakes in that same method, whether I did or not? Which of the possible `SuppressWarnings` categories do you recommend for my situation, Santiago? None of the ones you link to seems to apply.

Comment: Not familiar with FindBugs or what @SuppressWarnings values it supports!  OP should use the narrowest value that eliminates his warning, to address your concern above.

Comment: What FindBugs reported when you used "unused"? Normally that one works best.

Comment: `SuppressWarnings` is a source-only annotation. It's invisible to byte-code analyzers like FindBugs.

Comment: It seems that FindBugs has its own suppress warnings: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/annotations/SuppressFBWarnings.html

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I came across the same problem. I was using `ProcessBuilder` to run the 'other' process whose stdout I wanted to attach.

If we are using ProcessBuilder to manage the other process, then since java 9 we can redirect the output.

`processBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.DISCARD)`

From documentation;

> Indicates that subprocess output will be discarded. A typical implementation discards the output by writing to an operating system specific "null file"

```
public static final Redirect DISCARD = new Redirect() {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting. The `InputStream` in question happens to be from `ProcessBuilder`, and we've recently upgraded beyond Java 8, so this might be an opportunity for us to simplify some of our code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = ...;
boolean report = ...;
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (report) {
        Debug.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had hopped to avoid having to re-evaluate `report` on each iteration of the loop. Perhaps the optimizer takes care of that, but I'd prefer not to *rely* on any particular optimization. Also, doesn't this end of constructing and destroying a lot of strings that I don't really need?